# Why logo-image is not rendering in email template in html sent through nodemailer

Tags: html, html-email, nodemailer

```html
 <div class="top"   display=flex >
        <div>
        <p>Date/Time: <span id="date-time"></span></p>
        <script>
         var dt = new Date();
         document.getElementById('date-time').innerHTML=dt;
         </script>
        </div>
        <div align=right>
         <img href="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2F2015%2F9%2F1%2F9239769%2Fnew-google-logo-announced&psig=AOvVaw09j8UfowDYSj2kpOO7UnqB&ust=1625896727471000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAoQjRxqFwoTCOi17bqn1fECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI"   alt="logo"  width="16"  height="16" > 
        </div>

    </div>
```

I have search earlier and found that we have to give image url and I tried using it but it is still not displaying image.

the image is the screenshot of the email received
[image: the image is the screenshot of the email received]

Comment: Both the answers point you in the right direction but please dont link images linked from google search. You will damage your sender reputation and cause the IP and/or sender name might be blacklisted.

Answer (score 2):

You have specified the wrong attribute for  tag, you will need to add src, not href, so your tag would be like this

```
<img src="https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.theverge.com%2F2015%2F9%2F1%2F9239769%2Fnew-google-logo-announced&psig=AOvVaw09j8UfowDYSj2kpOO7UnqB&ust=1625896727471000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAoQjRxqFwoTCOi17bqn1fECFQAAAAAdAAAAABAI"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two errors:

1. You use `img href=""` instead of `img src=""`
2. You use an image url that is a redirected link from google.com to the image location. You need to use a clean https://.. link.

If you fix these two your code will work.